# TVShow Renamer Run Solely Through Bash/Terminal

Tags: 14.04, scripts, rename

I come from Windows and used therenamer religiously.  Is there something similar that can be used on Linux (I saw filebot...maybe) that can also be used through a bash script/terminal commands?

Meaning, I would have a script scan a directory and anytime there is a new file added this file would then be run through the tvdb or imdb database to get the "proper" name.

Answer (score 1):

FileBot is a command-line tool that you can use in your shell scripts: http://www.filebot.net/cli.html